# Is it possible to bind multiple print buttons in multiple modals to a specific div in each modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm working on a page through the foundation 5 framework that has a table of information, each one with a link to bring up a specific modal containing detailed information on that specific row. I'm interested in having a "print this information" button for the div contained within each modal. my code is similar to the following:

```html
<div id="detailModal1">
   <a href="javascript:window.print()" class="button"></i>Print Modal 1 Info</a>
   <div id="printableInfo1">Modal 1 information here</div>
</div>


<div id="detailModal2">
   <a href="javascript:window.print()" class="button"></i>Print Modal 2 Info</a>
   <div id="printableInfo2">Modal 2 information here</div>
</div>

<div id="detailModal3">
   <a href="javascript:window.print()" class="button"></i>Print Modal 3 Info</a>
   <div id="printableInfo2">Modal 3 information here</div>
</div>
```

Hopefully this was specific enough, I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: was I able to answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@media print` css query selector to specify what should appear on the printed page.

In the below example I'm hiding everything on the printed page and then applying a class `print-content` when a the user clicks a button.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.min.js"></script>

<style>
    @media print {
        html body * {
            display: none;
        }
        .print-content {
            display: block !important;
        }
        .print-content * {
            display: block !important;
        }
    }
</style>


<div id="detailModal1">
    <a href="#" class="button print-button"></i>Print Modal 1 Info</a>
    <div id="printableInfo1">Modal 1 information here</div>
</div>
<div id="detailModal2" class="print">
    <a href="#" class="button print-button"></i>Print Modal 2 Info</a>
    <div id="printableInfo2">Modal 2 information here</div>
</div>
<div id="detailModal3">
    <a href="#" class="button print-button"></i>Print Modal 3 Info</a>
    <div id="printableInfo2">Modal 3 information here</div>
</div>

<script>

    $('.print-button').click(function(e) {
        var printContainer = $(e.target).parent();
        printContainer.addClass('print-content')
        window.print()
        printContainer.removeClass('print-content')
    })

</script>
```

Comment: Hey Daniel, sorry it took a while to get back! This actually did not work with my code, which I suspect is in part due to some other elements within it, but my team actually decided to go in a different direction design-wise, so I haven't been able to further investigate the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Okay thanks for the reponse @brandonalexanderharwood However, it does work inside the snippet though correct?